# Density of simple functions in Bochner space for $p > 1$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Given a Banach space $X$, we say a function $f:[0,T] \to X$ is strongly measurable if there exists a sequence of simple functions ($E_i$ Lebesgue measurable and $c_i \in X$)
$$s_k(t) = \sum_{i = 1}^{n(k)} \chi_{E_i}(t)c_i$$
such that 
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} s_k(t) = f(t)$$
for almost every $t \in [0,T]$.  We then say that a strongly measurable function $f$ is integrable if there exist simple functions such that 
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \int_0^T \|s_k(t) - f(t)\|_X dt = 0.$$ 
The space $L^p(0,T;X)$ ($1 \le p < \infty$) is then defined as the strongly measurable functions that satisfy $$\int_0^T \|f(t)\|_X^p dt < \infty.$$

$\textbf{MY QUESTION}$ regards the approximation of functions in $L^p(0,T;X)$ by simple functions. I am aware that in the usual case of a Lebesgue measurable function $f \in L^p(\mathbb{R})$ on the real line we can take a sequence of simple functions $s_k$ such that $s_k(x) \to f$ pointwise and such that $|s_k(x)| \uparrow |f(x)|$. In this case we have that  $|s_k(x) - f(x)|^p \to 0$ pointwise and $|s_k - f|^p \le C(|s_k|^p + |f|^p) \le 2C|f|^p \in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, and hence by the dominated convergence theorem we conclude that $\|s_k - f\|_{L^p} \to 0$. Can someone show me how to generalize this argument to the Bochner space case? In particular, I am not sure how to argue that 
$$\int_0^T \|s_k(t)\|_X^pdt < M < \infty$$
uniformly in $k$ so that we can pass to the limit in 
$$\int_0^T \|s_k(t) - f(t)\|_X^pdt$$
with the dominated convergence theorem. I am asking this question because I want a direct proof (something that does not rely on mollification) that continuous functions from $[0,T]$ into $X$ are dense in $L^p(0,T;X)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{s_k\}$ be a sequence of simple functions with $s_k \to f$ pointwise a.e.

For $i = 0,\ldots,k^2$, we define
$$\Omega_{k,i} := \Bigl\{t \in [0,T] \mid \frac ik \le \| f(t) \| \le \frac{i+1}k \Bigr\}.$$
Now, we set
$$
\hat s_k(t) = \begin{cases}
\frac{s_k(t)}{\|s_k(t)\|} \, \min\Bigl\{ \frac ik, \|s_k(t)\|\Bigr\} & \text{if } t \in \Omega_{k,i} \text{ for some } i=0,\ldots,k^2, \\
0 & \text{else.}
\end{cases}$$
Then, $\hat s_k$ is a simple function,
we still have $\hat s_k \to f$ pointwise a.e.
and, additionally, $\|s_k\| \le \|f\|$ pointwise a.e.